# Azure resources using a specific subnet

Tags: azure

Recently while working on application gateway, I came to know that application gateway can’t be provisioned using a subnet which is being used by other resources and we need to create a separate subnet for application gateways.

Now I have differentiate which all resources are using a specific subnet in order to separate subnets between VMs and gateways.

Can you please let me know if there is any available Rest api to get the resources list that provisioned using a specific subnet. For example subnet XYZ is being used to provision VMs V1 V2 V3. So how can I get the list of VMs V1,V2 and V3 by providing the subnet name in url using rest api.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Naveen.

Answer (score 1):

There's not an easy way to achieve this using the REST API. You would have to get a list of all virtual machines, then get their NICs to list the subnets they are attached to and then categorize using that.

The other option is to use [Azure Resource Graph](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/governance/resource-graph/) to query your resources. The query below will get you the count of resources whos first NIC is in each subnet:

```
az graph query -q "where type =~ 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces'  | extend subnet = properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.subnet | summarize count() by tostring(subnet)
```

This assumes you run this using the CLI, but in theory it is possible to use resource graph using the REST API - [see here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azureresourcegraph/resources/resources)